# Error When Deploying Quick Action With Predefined Lookup Field

Tags: salesforcedx, lookup, salesforcedx-cli, quickaction

I have a Quick Action which works fine and has predefined field to a lookup record, AddressType, though it happens in all cases. When deploying to scratch org I get error

> Formula result is data type (Text), incompatible with expected data type (Lookup(Address Type)).

Formula return now is `MasterObject.AddressType__c`. I also tried `MasterObject.AddressType__r.Id`. Neither works same error in both (second one makes sense though). How do we reference these so they can be deployed to scratch orgs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few hours of frustration but using the reference

> CustomObject__c.Lookup__c

works in the Quick Action but not in the deploy. Have to use

> CustomObject__r.Lookup__c

.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what does sfdx pull/metadata api retrieve return? Is that CustomObject__r or CustomObject__c ?

Comment: CustomObject__c. That was a large part of the issue since they are inconsistent in how they treat this.